# how to pass multiple arguments to thread for client server in c?

Tags: c, multithreading, sockets

I want to create a concurrent server to work on multiple client request. So I created a thread function to handle multiple request . My problem is I have a hash table , it is loaded with contents of file initially whenever server start and I have socket descriptor, file descriptor too. So how can I pass to thread function .Is it required structure to store the arguments and pass to thread ?

my code is like this :

```
struct UserData
{
    char *username; 
    char *password;

};

struct HashTable
 {
    int size;
    struct UserData *table
 };

int main()
{
 struct HashTable *htable;
  //socket sd to open socket in server
  and a Fd file descriptor to write to file
 // hash table loaded with contents and it is a structure
 /*create thread using pthread*/
 pthread_create(...,fun,..);

 }

 void * fun(void *arg)
 {
  .............
  }
```

how I declare a structure for passing to thread function including the arguments like socket descriptor (sd) ,file descriptor(fd) and hash table pointer ? will I use mutex to lock when I writing to file (fd) ?

Comment: Is your question really "how do I declare a structure?"  You've already demonstrated above that you know how to declare a structure.  What are you asking?

Comment: You just don't know how to put wrap those values into a struct and pass it to thread function? Do all threads share the same fd/sd (since you are asking about lock)?

Answer (score 2):

`pthread_create()` takes a `void *` as its final argument, which gets passed to your thread entry function, `fun()` in your case. So you would just need to define a struct that contains all the fields you want to pass:

```
struct ThreadArg {
    int sd; /* socket descriptor */
    int fd; /* file descriptor */
    struct HashTable *ht;
};
```

Then in your `main()` you fill it in and pass it to `pthread_create()`:

```
...
struct ThreadArg *arg = malloc(sizeof(struct ThreadArg)); /* you should check for NULL */
arg->sd = sd;
arg->fd = fd;
arg->ht = htable;
pthread_create(..., fun, (void *)arg);
...
```

And in `fun()` you cast it back:

```
void *fun(void *arg) {
    struct ThreadArg *thArg = (struct ThreadArg *)arg;
    /* do whatever with thArg->sd, thArg->fd, etc. */
    ...
    /* free the memory when done */
    free(arg);
}
```

Comment: how to assign values to inside struct HashTable ..Is it like tharg->ht-= malloc(sizeof(struct HashTable)) and can I assign tharg->ht->table=malloc(size * sizeof(struct UserData)) and also like

Comment: and also like this   for (i = 0; i < htable->size; i++)
        {
                htable->table[i].username = NULL;
                htable->table[i].password = NULL;
        }